# Iterating over 2-dimensional STL vector c++

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I'm currently trying to print out a history of movements for players in a game I am working on. At the end of each round every player has moved some amount in the positive or negative direction and this gets recorded as an int in the movement vector. Eventually I'm wanting to plot the directions moved vs time for each player but I'm having trouble extracting the data out of the 2d vector.

So the first thing I tried was to just iterate and print all the elements, however this doesn't compile:

```
void output_movement(const std::vector< std::vector<int> > & movement){

    std::vector< std::vector<int> >::iterator row;
    std::vector<int>::iterator col;
    for (row = movement.begin(); row != movement.end(); ++row) {
         for (col = row->begin(); col != row->end(); ++col) {
            std::cout << **col;
         }
    }

}
```

The compiler gives this error message which I don't really understand:

```
hg_competition.cpp:45: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘row = ((const std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >*)money_movement)->std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::begin [with _Tp = std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >]()’
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_iterator.h:669: note: candidates are: __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >*, std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > >& __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >*, std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > >::operator=(const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >*, std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > >&)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to use a `const_iterator` if the `vector` is a const reference. Also, to output `col` you only need to dereference it once.

```
void output_movement(const std::vector< std::vector<int> > & movement){

    std::vector< std::vector<int> >::const_iterator row;
    std::vector<int>::const_iterator col;
    for (row = movement.begin(); row != movement.end(); ++row) {
         for (col = row->begin(); col != row->end(); ++col) {
            std::cout << *col;
         }
    }
}
```

Edit: using typedefs will make your code more readable

```
typedef std::vector<int> Vector;
typedef std::vector<Vector> DoubleVector;

void output_movement(
    const DoubleVector& movement
)
{
    for (DoubleVector::const_iterator row = movement.begin(); row != movement.end(); ++row) {
         for (Vector::const_iterator col = row->begin(); col != row->end(); ++col) {
            std::cout << *col;
         }
         std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would argue that if you're going to rewrite the code, it could be worthwhile to also properly put `row` and `col` declarations within the `for` loop for proper scoping.

Comment: Also it would perhaps be a bit more C++-like if `output_movement` were called `operator<<`.

Comment: @Philipp: I am not sure. Overloading operator is always tricky, especially when there could be several possible displays.

Answer (score 12):

The 2D `vector` is declared `const`, so you need to use `const_iterator` instead of `iterator`.

You also shouldn't doubly dereference `col`. It is an iterator, so you only need to dereference once.

```
void output_movement(const std::vector< std::vector<int> > & movement){ 

    std::vector< std::vector<int> >::const_iterator row; 
    std::vector<int>::const_iterator col; 
    for (row = movement.begin(); row != movement.end(); ++row) { 
         for (col = row->begin(); col != row->end(); ++col) { 
            std::cout << *col; 
         } 
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 4):

`const` objects return `const_iterators`, so simply replace `iterator` by `const_iterator` everywhere. This also prevents unwanted modifications of the vectors.

This is the combination of Sam's and Mathieu's suggestions:

```
#include <ostream>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<int> Vector;
typedef std::vector<Vector> DoubleVector;


template<typename Char, typename Traits>
std::basic_ostream<Char, Traits>&
operator<<(std::basic_ostream<Char, Traits>& stream,
           const DoubleVector& movement) {
    for (DoubleVector::const_iterator row = movement.begin(); row != movement.end(); ++row) {
         for (Vector::const_iterator col = row->begin(); col != row->end(); ++col) {
            stream << *col;
         }
    }
return stream;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

John, you suggested using lambdas, but if C++11 is available, I'd prefer

```
for (auto& row : movement) {
     for (auto& elem : row) {
        std::cout << elem;
     }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the clean range-based loops -- although there is no need for the '&', is there?

Comment: Christian: Yes there is! Otherwise, each row will be copied and iterated over. The second reference is not as crucial.

Comment: Ben: Oh, that: yes, certainly. But then you might as well write `const auto &` to make sure you don't accidentally change your `row`s or `elem`ents, no?

Answer (score 0):

Omg, *anything* is better than that mess of `for` loops. Here some alternatives. Choose whichever you like.

```
typedef vector<int> VI;
typedef vector<VI> VVI;


namespace std {
    ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const VI& v) {
        copy (v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout));
        return o;
    }
}
void output_movement (const VVI& m) {
    copy (m.begin (), m.end (), ostream_iterator<const VI&>(cout));
}
```

or,

```
void output_movement (const VVI & m) {
    for_each (m.begin(), m.end(), [](const VI& v){ 
                for_each (v.begin(), v.end(), [](int i){ cout << i; });
                });
}
```

or, my personal preference (boost/foreach.hpp),

```
void output_movement (const VVI & m) {
    foreach (const VI& v, m)
        foreach (int i, v)
            cout << i;
}
```