# How do I iterate through a two dimensional vector

Tags: c++, vector, multidimensional-array

To iterate through and print the elements of a single dimensional vector I use,

```
vector<int> a;
for(vector<int>::iterator it=a.begin();it<a.end();it++)
    cout<<*it;
```

How do I do the same for a two dimensional Vector?

Comment: That's depends what you mean by two-dimensional vector. `vector<vector<int>>`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iterating over 2-dimensional STL vector c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131991/iterating-over-2-dimensional-stl-vector-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or since we're using c++11...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {

  vector<vector<int> > v = {{1,2}, {3,4}};
  for (const auto& inner : v) {
      for (const auto& item : inner) {
          cout << item << " ";
      }
  }
  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that your example is also the easiest way to iterate through 2D vectors with different number of elements per column.

Answer (score 2):

If by two dimensional `vector` you mean `vector<vector<int> >`, this should work:

```
vector<vector<int> > v = {{1,2}, {3,4}};
for(auto beg = v.begin(); beg != v.end(); ++beg)
{
    for(auto ceg = beg->begin(); ceg != beg->end(); ++ceg) {
        cout << *ceg << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Outputs:

```
1 2
3 4
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/i2hgnt)