# Check whether an element exists in a 2D vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have inserted some elements in a 2D vector and want to know whether a given element is present in the 2D vector anywhere. Is there any quick way to find the presence of the element ?

The vector is declared as : `vector < vector< int > > v;`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571394/how-to-find-out-if-an-item-is-present-in-a-stdvector?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find out if an item is present in a std::vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571394/how-to-find-out-if-an-item-is-present-in-a-stdvector)

Comment: That is for 1D vector,I hope.

Comment: Did you mean `vector<vector<T>> v;` for some scalar type T?

Comment: You know how to search a vector? Then just search every vector in the vector in the same way.

Comment: `vector < vector > v;` is an error, you must give a template parameter for the inner vector

Comment: Well, I gave that as int inside angular brackets but  It vanished after posting !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have more information about the 2D vector (like somehow sorted), then the best way would be iterating over each row of the 2D vector and using `find` method to check if it exist or not.

You do something like the following:

```
bool does_exist(const vector< vector<int> >&  v, int item){

     vector< vector<int> >::const_iterator row;

    for (row = v.begin(); row != v.end(); row++) {
        if(find(row->begin(), row->end(), item) != row->end() )
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

You can test it with the follwing code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int item = 12;
    vector < vector <int> > v;
    vector <int> v1;

    v1.push_back(1);
    v1.push_back(2);
    v1.push_back(3);

    vector <int> v2;

    v2.push_back(4);
    v2.push_back(5);
    v2.push_back(6);

    v.push_back(v1);
    v.push_back(v2);

    if( does_exist(v, item))
        cout << "Item " << item << " exist" << endl;
    else 
        cout << "Item " << item << " does not exist" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not as elegant as I had hoped for. Given a 2D vector of int's:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> foo = {
    {{1, 2, 3}},
    {{5, 6, 7}},
    {{8, 9, 13, 15}}
};
```

you could do this to see if the 13 is present:

```
bool found =
    find_if(foo.begin(), foo.end(),
            [](const std::vector<int>& v) -> bool {
                return find(v.begin(), v.end(), 13) != v.end();
            }) != foo.end();
```

Comment: Really, not much elegant as an answer as I had hoped for. But, iterating would be much better !!

Comment: I prefer functional methods over imperative approaches like iteration, but dang C++ lambda syntax is ugly.

Comment: Does the time complexity in any of the 2 approaches change ?

Comment: Using functional programming style typically  gives room for the compiler to optimize more, but I recommend using what you think is clearer. Both are linear O(N) searches.

Comment: @wcochran *"Using functional programming style typically gives room for the compiler to optimize more"* Can you point to resources that drive the idea home? I would like to read more.

Comment: @CinCout The main idea is that you are not specifying *how* to find the element (e.g., with an explicit loop), so the STL `find`/`find_if` implementation has more freedom to generate whatever code it deems best. In fact, `find` / `find_if` are "embarrassingly parallel" in this case --  e.g., a compiler could generate SIMD compare instructions on slices of the vector. To go even farther there exist parallel versions of STL algorithms : e.g., https://software.intel.com/en-us/get-started-with-pstl

Comment: @CinCout There are paralyzed versions `find` and `find_if` in the `std::experimental::parallel` space: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/parallelism/existing
I imagine this will be standard for future C++ STL implementation.

Comment: @wcochran So by *functional programming", you meant STL algorithms and not explicit loops?! I interpreted it in reverse, hence the question.

Comment: @CinCout loops are an imperative construct, not a functional one. STL algorithms and lambdas are C++’s attempt to provide functional programming methods. Not as powerful as Lisp or Haskel in this area, but a good way forward.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

Use **[std::find()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)**.

In C++, please use the function from **[Standard Template Library (STL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library)** if it has been provided.

### Elaboration

Let's say you have an 2d vector

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > matrix = {
   {1,2,3}, 
   {4,5,6},
   {7,8,9}
};
```

And if you want to iterate over all the elements in the 2d vector above.

I recommend you to use 2d `iterator`:

```
bool element_exist(const vector< vector<int> >&  input, int key){
    // 2d vector iterator
    vector< vector<int> >::iterator row_it; //iterate over each row(s)
    vector<int>::iterator col_it; //iterate over column(s)
    for (row_it = input.begin(); row_it != input.end(); row_it++) { // iterate each row(s)
        for (col_it = row_it->begin(); row_it != row_it->end(); col_it++) {
            if(find(row_it->begin(), row_it->end(), key) != row_it->end())
                return true;
        }
    }
}
```

and you can use another boolean variable to get the return value of the function `key_exist`

```
bool_var = element_exist(matrix, key);
```

### Whole program

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool element_exist(const vector< vector<int> >&  input, int key){
    // 2d vector iterator
    vector< vector<int> >::const_iterator row_it; //iterate over each row(s)
    vector<int>::const_iterator col_it; //iterate over column(s)
    for (row_it = input.begin(); row_it != input.end(); row_it++) { // iterate each row(s)
        for (col_it = row_it->begin(); row_it != row_it->end(); col_it++) {
            if(find(row_it->begin(), row_it->end(), key) != row_it->end())
                return true;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    // declaration
    bool bool_var = false; // default false
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > matrix = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6},{7,8,9}};

    bool_var = element_exist(matrix,1);
    cout << "bool_var: " << bool_var << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

### Result

```
bool_var: 1
```

Comment: somebody mentioned this post, so I put it here: [How to find out if an item is present in a std::vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571394/how-to-find-out-if-an-item-is-present-in-a-stdvector?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: more info [Iterating over 2-dimensional STL vector c++
][https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131991/iterating-over-2-dimensional-stl-vector-c]